# jQuery OOP basics

Tags: jquery, oop

I want to start developing jQuery games, thus I need to learn jQuery OOP. I have some (enough) experience with C++ OOP (developed some games).

I know that I can replace the C++ "class" with jQuery "objects" but I don't know how exactly that works.

Also does jQuery have more advanced "options" like C++ ? (abstract classes/objects, inheirtance, etc... )

Can you guys explain that to me? (or give me the link to some good javascript OOP tutorials).

Comment: The first thing to do is convince yourself that JavaScript is far more **different** from C++ than it is similar.

Comment: Yes I know, but OOP is "the same" in all programming languages (+ / - ), just the syntax is different :D

Comment: Oh, and note that jQuery is just a JavaScript library - it's not a distinct language. What you should do is learn JavaScript the language, and then learn the jQuery APIs (or whatever other toolkit you choose; jQuery is not the only choice).

Comment: you should learn javascript oop first, not jQuery.

Comment: @Cristy that statement is definitely not true at all - object-oriented programming in JavaScript is significantly different in fundamental ways than object-oriented programming in C++.

Comment: You're right, but I've been using jQuery for some time and I want to go "to the next level". It can't be that difficult, I just need a "link" to start with :)

Comment: @Felix, yes, I meant javascript...

Comment: Well then I'd start with [this page at O'Reilly media](http://oreilly.com/javascript/).

Comment: @Cristy: The next level would be to learn JavaScript properly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide, especially https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: "jQuery games" You don't make games with jQuery. You could use jQuery to build a rendering engine on top off though.

Comment: no, I can't but it's helpful. I can easily edit CSS,create animations, etc... It's a good library, there's no need to "reinvent the wheel"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

OOP programming in JavaScript can be done in many ways. There are a lot of patterns around.

I will show you two, an Implementation of object inheritance and an implementation of object composition.

This does have absolutely nothing to do with jQuery. jQuery should be used for DOM manipulation and event manipulation. You shouldn't make your core objects and constructors based on jQuery objects. In a game jQuery's role is reading keyboard input and optionally rendering your graphics into the DOM (If you're not using the `<canvas>` for some reason).

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ALHDz/)

**Inheritance**

```
var Constructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name
};

Constructor.prototype.mymethod = function() {
    alert("my name is : " + this.name);
};

var obj = new Constructor("foo");
obj.mymethod(); // my name is : foo
```

Here were defining a `Constructor` function that you can call to create a new object. You refer to the object inside the constructor with `this`.

You can add (static) methods and variables to the prototype of the Constructor that will be inherited by the object.

```
function inherits(child, parent) {
    var f = new Function;
    f.prototype = parent.prototype;
    f.prototype.constructor = parent;
    child.prototype = new f;
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
}
```

You may use an `inherits` function which set's the prototype of a constructor function to an instance of a different constructor. This means that all the methods and properties of that parent object are available on the child

```
var SecondConstructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name + "bar";
};
inherits(SecondConstructor, Constructor);
var obj = new SecondConstructor("foo");
obj.mymethod(); // my name is : foobar
```

This is JavaScripts prototypical inheritance. Basically you set the prototype of a function to a particular object. Then when you use the function to create objects those objects implement the prototype.

**Composition**

Using the prototype isn't actually neccesary you can also use object composition instead. This method does require a good understanding of the `this` state which you can read about [elsewhere](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#this).

I'm going to cheat and delegate some of the tedious helper functions to [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

```
var Constructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name;

    this.mymethod = function() {
        alert("my name is : " + this.name);
    };
};

var SecondConstructor = function(name) {
    var constructor = new Constructor(name + "bar");
    _.bindAll(constructor);
    _.extend(this, {
        "mymethod": constructor.mymethod
    });
};

var obj = new SecondConstructor("foo");
obj.mymethod();
```

Here the SecondConstructor creates an instance of Constructor for itself rather then inheriting from it. It then binds the reference of `this` on all the methods of that constructor object so that we can delegate the call to `mymethod` to our own constructor object. This only works for methods but that shouldn't be an issue because you really shouldn't have public fields.

Comment: @Cristy personally I recommend the second one and adopting a more functional approach like say python/ruby rather then C++.

Comment: FYI, in your Inheritance example, you show "this.myname" in the constructor but then refer to it as "this.name" in the method.

Answer (score 4):

OOP is very much *not* the same in all programming languages.  Objects in C++ are instances of classes, and classes are an entirely compile-time construct.  Javascript doesn't have classes, all it has are objects.

It is possible to use Javascript in ways that act similarly to classes, using scoping rules, prototype chains and the special "this" reference, but these are idioms that are imposed on the language, not part of the language.  And there are quite a few different class-style idioms in common use, and untold numbers of self-invented ones.

In my mind, the critical differences between javascript and C++/C#/Java/etc., are best understood by exploring the scoping rules.  What variables are in scope at any point in the code, and what object the special "this" reference is pointing to, when, are what it is critical to understand, when trying to work with javascript.

Comment: also an understanding of prototypical inheritance is important.

Answer (score 3):

As a note, I've recently started using [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) which allows the declaration of classes C++ - like, simply using 'class' .

**Later Edit (June 2014):**

Processing.js was good for getting projects going without having to *fight* with JavaScript OOP. But as I started developing larger projects I noticed that Processing.js is a level too much of abstractization and that it is actually worth writing the OOP bits and whole code structure by yourself.

I am now using [PIXI.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) as my canvas renderer/interaction library and structure my code in a much more cleaner way using some of the OOP tricks mentioned above.