# qTip2 and Object Oriented Programming

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm developing a calendar and I would like to open a qTip2 tooltip when an user clicks on a calendar cell.

I'm trying to develop my jQuery code following the OOP principles, according to the suggestions given by [Raynos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134494/1148260). So I tried with a very basic example, just putting my code in the constructor and calling it in the HTML of the cell.

Here you are the HTML code

```
<td onclick="new CalendarEvent('2012-10-22')" id="2012-10-22">
```

and the Javascript one

```
var CalendarEvent = function (date) 
{
    this.date = date;

    $('#'+this.date).qtip({
            content: 
            {
                text: 'Lorem ipsum',
                title: {
                    text: 'Lorem ipsum',
                    button: true
                }
            },
            position: {
                    my: 'left center', 
                    at: 'center'
            },
            show: {             
                    solo : true 
            },
            hide: 'click',
            style: {
                    tip: true,
                    classes: 'ui-tooltip-light'
            }
    });
}
```

Many problems:

- when I click on a cell, nothing happens but the tooltip appears when I move the cursor out of the cell and then I hover on the cell again;
- the close button doesn't work;
- clicking on a second cell, the first tooltip is closed and a new one is opened but when I hover on the first cell the old tooltip appears again.

Obviously when a use the same code in procedural way, everything is ok...

Thank you

Comment: First of all, the OOP approach does not mean you cannot use procedures (nor does it excuse the excessive use of `new`). Think of it like this; do you really want to create an object on each mouse click? Instead, you should bind a function to the element event. Giving elements non-unique ids is also a bad idea; what if you had two calendars on the same page?

Comment: What do you mean for "bind a function to the element event"? I'm not so good in js, could you post a link when I can study this issue? In my page, there is just one calendar but I see your point... thank you

Comment: Assuming you want the above code to work with all td's in table with class calendar, you would use: `jQuery('table.calendar td').click(function(){ /* rest of the code goes here */ });`

Comment: Ok thank you. Just another question. I decided to use the OOP way because I have to manage many action such as creating, editing, deleting calendar events throught AJAX forms showed within tooltips. Is this, in your experience, a bad design choice (for the excessive use of new as you said before)? I thought at OOP approach for better code reusability, maintenability and simplicity but you know, I'm not a js ninja!

Comment: I didn't suggest not using oop, I just said that excessive use of `new` isn't optimal oop either.